# How to get JSON array as var in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm lost on getting a chart to work.
I've got a query on PHP from MySQL, already working, which outputs $`data` as JSON. Example: `.: [[1,10],[2,25]...]`.

How to get this to work on this code?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data1 = [[1,10],[2,25]...];
var data2 = [[1,1],[2,20]...];
$("#flot-dashboard-chart").length && $.plot($("#flot-dashboard-chart"), 
[data1, data2],
{
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: false,
            fill: true
        },
        splines: {
            show: true,
            tension: 0.4,
            lineWidth: 1,
            fill: 0.4
        },
        points: {
            radius: 0,
            show: true
        },
        shadowSize: 2
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true,
        tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: '#d5d5d5'
    },
    colors: ["#1ab394", "#1C84C6"],
    xaxis:{
    },
    yaxis: {
        ticks: 4
    },
    tooltip: false
    }
  );    
)};
```

Comment: not very clear what you get from php, but perhaps you echo the array from php, in which case you might want to use json_encode($array)

Comment: Thanks for your repy. I've got a query from mysql with an array : while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $dash_data[] = array(count($data)+1, $row['subtotal']);
  
 }, thanks

Comment: what do you do with the dash data array?

Comment: I want to get the data as var data1 and var data2 on the js code. As, ex.: var data1 = [[0,10],[1,15],[2,11]...];

Comment: But what does your php code look like? You should have something like var data1 = <?php echo json_encode($dash_data); ?>;

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just learning an I'm also my english not the best. So if I'm geting you right i-I have a dashboard.php file wher I want a chart to show, with a div with the id #flot-dashboard-chart, then another file dashboard_data.php where the query to retrive data from mysql lies, with a loop while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ $dash_data[] = array(count($data)+1, $row['subtotal']); }, where I can " echo json_encode (($dash_data), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);", witch guives'me the right format I need as an array of data series. The problem now is to get this data working on the jquery file!?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the data attribute in HTML. `<div id="flot-dashboard-chart" data-json="<?=$data?>"></div>`. In JS you can call `var data1 = $('#flot-dashboard-chart').data('json');`.

Comment: Hi Tim Vermaelen, thanks for your answer but that didn't work... :(